# How do you set the AzureAD redirect url when using Microsoft.Identity.Web

Tags: asp.net-core, web-applications, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a little app setup and it is using a blue/green deployment strategy. Everything works correctly when running locally however once it is deployed the login hits a redirect loop until the browser throws a `400.15` error. The issue appears to be because of the reverse proxy where the request is being sent with the applications url but then the redirect url is pointing at localhost. Below is a sample url that I am being directed to, you will notice that the redirect_uri is pointed to `localhost` instead of example.com

https://example.com/b4e19cf5-ed91-44d3-81ce-70c848fa6841/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=REALLY_LONG_STRING&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0

I was able to find somewhat of an answer [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/issues/118) however this is a resolution from before the `Microsoft.Identity.Web` nuget package existed. Now the recommendation is to use the `.AddSignIn()` extension in the startup class and I am not sure how I can go about adding the property that is referenced in the git issue.

Comment: This may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I looked that over and it more seems to be dealing with the actual configuration of the proxy to receive requests. My configuration is fine and is working. It was once I tried to add the AzureAD authentication part that things fell over.

Basically the scenario is that the request comes into example.com which is then forwarded to localhost:8080, the site realizes that its not authenticated and reaches out to login.microsoft.com but with the redirect url as shown above. Some sort of mismatch happens which causes a redirect loop until the error is thrown

Comment: We had similar problems but not with AzureAD. The critical point is, that your asp core app needs to know the correct host name and scheme to be able to generate the correct redirect uri. This cannot work out of the box behind reverse proxy and you need to enable it as described in linked docs. You could create a test action echoing `Request.Host, Request.Scheme`, it should output example.com. If not, check forwarded headers middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this should be addressed by htts://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web#115 (soon to be implemented in Microsoft.identity.Web)

I've also provided a work around in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/115#issuecomment-620527830